# PhoneGap Android: Google map api v3 showing blank screen

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cordova

I am building an webapp using phonegap cordova 2.9.0. The app developed is working fine in the desktop browser but when i try to run app in android device (After getting build using [build_tool](https://build.phonegap.com)  it shows the first alert generated by my javascript. After that only a blank white screen appears nothing else.

The link to the app source at is [link](https://github.com/aksswami/aks-bitmap.git). In this app i am trying to get users current location using

```
navigator.geolocation
```

The app aims to show all available bitcoin trade places in google map withing given radius of user location.

App can be downloaded using this [link](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/535538/share).

Update:

I am able to get the geolocation points and show them in alert, but wehn i try to render them on map with marker, then map is not rendering on android device. (Working on desktop browser)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./main.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CoinMap</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>    
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA-zLxKvbiIbO8uR20Z5DemPXYh1F3bm1M&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="js/coinmap.js"></script><!--
<script src="js/coinmap-icons.js"></script>-->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="bitcoin.png" />
<meta name="keywords" content="coinmap,map,bitcoin,openstreetmap" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--<body onload="getCoinData()">-->
<div id="map"></div>
    <div id="count"></div>
    <script>
        alert("Getting your location....");
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(coinmap, onError, {maximumAge: 300000, timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy : true});

            }
            else{
            alert("GeoLocation is not available.");}
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**coinmap.js**

```
    function coinmap(position) {
    alert("Latitude: "  + position.coords.latitude   + "\n" +
         "Longitude:" + position.coords.longitude  + "\n");
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    loadMap(lat, lng);
}


function loadMap(latitude, longitude){

    var my_latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: my_latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    var my_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: my_latLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'My Position'
    });

    var markers = [];
    var user_radius = 1000000;
    $.getJSON("http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=[out:json];(node[%22payment:bitcoin%22=yes];way[%22payment:bitcoin%22=yes];%3E;);out;", function (data) {

        $.each(data.elements, function (key, value) {

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                'position': latLng
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        });

        // Define the circle
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            clickable: false,
            // metres
            radius: user_radius,
            fillColor: '#fff',
            fillOpacity: .6,
            strokeColor: '#313131',
            strokeOpacity: .4,
            strokeWeight: .8
        });
        // Attach circle to marker
        circle.bindTo('center', my_marker, 'position');
        // Get the bounds
        var bounds = circle.getBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (bounds.contains(markers[i].getPosition())) {
                markers[i].setMap(map);
            } else {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }

    });
}


function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

This above code is working well in chrome and firefox and mobile browser also, but not working as a wepapp after build using phonegap. Any help will be appreciated.

Any geolocation example with rendering location on map can also be helpful.

Comment: Did you use phonegap´s own API to get the geo locations?   I dident look in your code, but it could be an interesting thing for you to look at :-)

Comment: yes i used phonegap's own api to get geo locations. It is described here [Phonegap Geolocaton](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation)

Comment: @Aks did you solve your problem yet or not?
i also stuck on this problem and i am getting error on this line usually `marker.setMap(map);` when i tried to put marker or polygons on map through `try-catch` i checked the error and error is  `Object is not a Function`

Comment: i am not able to resolve the problem in phonegap. but i was able to do it on a website <http://thestartupzone.in/> . This website is not complete, i am working on it. Please provide more details about your problem. Maybe some code snippet will help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same problem and found the issue to be with the options passed in.  If you look at the current example on phonegap.com for getCurrent location: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation

You'll notice no options are passed in, it's simply: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

I deleted my options and the map popped right up.  I have not looked deeper into it since, so I cannot tell you the cause, but please try deleting your options and see if it works.

Comment: The page clearly describes opts as an optional argument navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,
                                         [geolocationError],
                                         [geolocationOptions]);